# Programming of ADC in PIC12F675: Not Working Properly

Tags: pic, c, embedded, programming, code

I'm new to embedded systems and I want to program a PIC12F675 for a project.

So, the idea is that there is a switch. If the switch is off, the microcontroller normally outputs a clock signal, which its frequency is controlled by a potentiometer. And if the switch is on, there is another button that I can push to output a pulse that lasts for 500ms and goes low again.

I wrote the code, but it seems to not be working correctly.
Also I didn't code the potentiometer part because I don't know how, so it outputs a clock that it's frequency can't be controlled.

## The problem:

When the switch is off (mode = 0), the clock doesn't work. However, when the switch is on (mode = 1), the clock works. It should be the other way around. Also, the pulse button doesn't work in either modes. Lastly, as I said before, I didn't code the potentiometer part because I don't know how.

So, could someone help me with this?
Thank you.

[image]

Here's the config:

```
#pragma config FOSC = INTRCCLK  
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF       
#pragma config BOREN = ON       
#pragma config CP = OFF         
#pragma config CPD = OFF
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <xc.h>
#include "config.h"
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

void dClock(int delay){
    GPIO2 = 1;
    __delay_ms(delay);
    GPIO2 = 0;
    __delay_ms(delay);
}

void main(void) {
    TRISIO2 = 0; //output
    TRISIO3 = 1; //mode
    TRISIO5 = 1; //pulse_button

    char pressed = 0;
    GPIO2 = 0;

    while(1){
        __delay_ms(50);

        if(GPIO3 == 0){
            int delay = ADC_Read(); //Supposed to read analog value here
            dClock(delay);
        }
        else{
            if(GPIO5 == 1 && pressed == 0){
                GPIO2 = 1;
                __delay_ms(500);
                GPIO2 = 0;
                pressed = 1;
            }
            else if(GPIO5 == 0 && pressed == 1){
                pressed = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

## Edit:

I edited the code and config, and everything is working fine. Now, I'm just still missing the analog input of the potentiometer.

Comment: Why are you enabling MCLR as reset?

Comment: When your switch is off, your PIC is *reset* and your code is not running because you enabled MCLR with `#pragma config MCLRE = ON`.

Comment: Thank you so much, guys. It works properly now. Just one thing is missing. How to get analog input from the potentiometer?

Comment: Here you find the answer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFpSlw2EJ9E  Example code https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8iMbc-iQqlUbzFxWURKV0swTHM/view

Comment: I did all the steps in the video, but the ADC_Read(0) function didn't work.
I got this error: "Implicit declaration of function ADC_Read is not valid in C99"

Comment: Tips: (1) Turn off the grid when taking screengrabs. It improves legibility. (2) Earth / ground symbols should point down towards the Earth / ground. (3) Positive power connection arrows should point up. It's not clear whether those arrows to the right are power connections or jumps to another sheet. (4) You have no current limiting resistor in D1. If it's there in reality it should be on the schematic. (5) U1 has no power and GND connections. This means that we can't be sure that you have included these or that they're using the same supply as other components and may be part of your problem.

Comment: @Transistor Thanks for the tips. I edited everything. Regarding the last point, the power is connected automatically in proteus.

Comment: Good work. It's a lot more legible now. +1.

Comment: @AliAboShady   "Implicit declaration of function ADC_Read is not valid in C99" Did you write `#include <xc.h>` in the beginning of your code. I didn't see one in the Google Drive's code, it is a bug.

Comment: @比尔盖子 Yes, I wrote "#include <xc.h>" in the beginning.

Comment: @AliAboShady  Okay, it seems `ADC_Read()` is not even a standard XC8 function, but was a library function of mikroC compiler or it has been defined at somewhere else by the author and it was not included in the example code. This is definitely a bad coding example. Perhaps you can try copying the `ADC_Read()` function from this tutorial and see whether it works. https://electrosome.com/adc-pic-microcontroller-mplab-xc8/ Make sure to put the function before `main()`.

Comment: Where did you read the Analogvalue? ' ADCRead()'  is not a standard function in xc8.

Comment: @Mike I got the ADC_Read() function from here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8iMbc-iQqlUbzFxWURKV0swTHM/view
In my code, I want to read the analog value before the "clock()" function.

Comment: which compiler are you using? ADC_Read is not a standard function in xc8, so you had to write it on your own.

Comment: @Mike Turns out I am using XC8. Okay I'll try writing it myself. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
   int delay = ADC_Read(); //Supposed to read analog value here
```

`ADC_Read()` is not a standard function supported by the xc8 compiler. You had to write it on your own.
Hint: Maybe you like to use the library [mcc](https://www.microchip.com/mplab/mplab-code-configurator)